# Nonsingular affine curve which is not unmixed

Tags: algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be any nonsingular curve in $A^3_{\mathbb C}$. Can a point be an irreducible component of $C$? I am not able to find an example of such $C$.

Comment: What is your definition of curve? I would say that a subvariety that has a point as an irreducible component is not a curve, simply because a point is 0-dimensional.

Comment: A curve is an affine scheme of finite type over a field $k$ of dimension one. Dimension of a scheme is the maximum of the dimensions of its finitely many irreducible components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that a point is an irreducible component of a variety if and only if its complement is closed, i.e. if and only if the point is isolated. So any example would be a disjoint union of another non-singular curve and a point.

The following equations cut out the disjoint union of a line and a point in the affine plane:
\begin{align}
x y & = 0 \\
x^2 - x & = 0
\end{align}
Thus it is seen that the coordinate ring of this affine variety is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[y] \times \mathbb{C}$, which is certainly of dimension 1. It is a regular variety in the sense that every local ring is regular, but perhaps you would not count it as non-singular, because the tangent space at the isolated point is 0-dimensional instead of 1-dimensional.